# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.exceptions'; 'urllib3' is not a package

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm using the following code to get data from a REST API:

```
import requests
import json

key = "my service key"

api = "http://api.data.go.kr/openapi/pblprfr-event-info-std?serviceKey=", key, "&s_page=1&s_list=100&type=json"


r = requests.get(api)

data = json.loads(r.text)

print(data["행사명"])
```

This code produces the following error:

> File "sel2.py", line 1, in <module>
>
> ```
> import requests
> ```
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/**init**.py", line 46, in <module>
>
> ```
> from .exceptions import RequestsDependencyWarning
> ```
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
>
> ```
> from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.exceptions'; 'urllib3' is not a package

Any ideas what the problem can be?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely something got corrupted in your `requests` installation or it's dependencies. The following fixed the issue, for me:

```sh
# Yeah, do them one-at-a-time, in case of errors:
pip uninstall urllib3
pip install --no-cache-dir -U urllib3
pip uninstall chardet
pip install --no-cache-dir -U chardet
```